# Find the maximum $P= \sqrt{x^3y+y^3z+z^3x}+\sqrt{xy^3+yz^3+zx^3} .$

Tags: inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

If   $ x, y, z\geq 0 $  and  $ x+y+z=3, $ then find the maximum:
$$P= \sqrt{x^3y+y^3z+z^3x}+\sqrt{xy^3+yz^3+zx^3} .$$

By Vasile's inequality $(x^2+y^2+z^2)^2\ge 3(x^3y+y^3z+z^3x)$ and $(x^2+y^2+z^2)^2\ge 3(x^3z+y^3x+z^3y)$, we get $$P\le 2\sqrt{3}(x^2+y^2+z^2).$$
But, it's obvious that $x^2+y^2+z^2\le (x+y+z)^2=9.$ Thus maximal value of $P=18\sqrt{3}.$

I want to ask whether my proof is correct or not. In case it's wrong, hope you can tell me where was my mistake.

Also, all ideas and comments are welcome.

Comment: You've got $P\leqslant 18\sqrt3$, which is fine. However for that to be a maximal value, you need to find some $x,y,z$ for which it is attainable.  In this case, you wont find any such values satisfying the condition as well, hence all you have is an upper bound, not a maximum.

Comment: Oh, I got it. Thank you @Macavity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Proof.**

By using Cauchy-Schwarz + AM-GM inequality,
$$\left(\sqrt{x^3y+y^3z+z^3x}+\sqrt{xy^3+yz^3+zx^3}\right)^2 \le 2(x^3y+y^3z+z^3x+xy^3+yz^3+zx^3) $$$$\le 2(xy+yz+zx)(x^2+y^2+z^2) \leq\frac{1}{4}\left (2(xy+yz+zx)+(x^2+y^2+z^2)\right) ^2 = \frac{1}{4}(x+y+z)^4.$$
Hence,$$\sqrt{x^3y+y^3z+z^3x}+\sqrt{xy^3+yz^3+zx^3} \le \frac{(x+y+z)^2}{2}=\frac{9}{2}.$$
In conclusion, maximum $P$ is $\dfrac{9}{2}$ achieve at $x=y=\dfrac{3}{2},\,z=0$ and permutations.

Comment: Good proof. Thanks